# Orbot - transparent proxying doesn't work

Tags: orbot

I'm using Orbot on my Android phone. It works great, but only for apps with native Orbot / proxy support. If I try to force other apps through Orbot using the "transparent proxying" setting, they lose their internet connection.

Any idea what's the issue here? Btw, I am using AFWall, but like I said, Orbot works great for Orbot-supporting apps, just the transparent proxying for other apps doesn't work.

Comment: I have this problem too. I think it's DNS what doesn't work, because intermittently I manage to open pages in Chrome, but most of time it complains on failed DNS. An implicit confirmation of this is that Chrome works when I select only Chrome for transparent proxying. But it doesn't when I choose all apps. The error is DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET. Update: If I manually add Orbot as proxy in Wi-Fi settings, Chrome works. But I don't know if all traffic is routed through Tor.